# Remove part of a string in Octave

Tags: string, octave

What is the most efficient way to remove part of a string and save it in one variable and the rest in other variable?

I tried something with substring but it's just to long. Does a function for this exist that i'm missing

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a function for that. You just use indexing:

```
a = "long string";
b = a(1:4);    # b is "long"
c = a(5:end);  # c is " string"
```

your problem then becomes finding the point where to split your string but that is dependent on your specific case. Possible functions for that are `strfind`, `strmatch`, `regexp`, and `index`.